# Как асинхронно обновить view во всех элементах списка нескольких Listview?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listview

Есть Viewpager.

В Viewpager по 25 Listview.

Каждый Listview содержит примерно по 30 - 50 позиций.

Позиция или item состоит из нескольких TextView и ImageView

Задача: Нужно обновлять пару TextView с периодичностью пару минут.
Пробовал обновлять адаптер Listview и вызывать метод notifyDataSetChanged() интерфейс виснет на полминуты.

Comment: Используйте RecyclerView тогда вы сможете обновлять не полностью все списки, а конкретные Item'ы, которые подверглись изменению, через метод notifyItemChanged(int position)

Comment: Не должен он на пару минут виснуть. С ViewPager по дефолту на экране фактически находится 3 ListView из 25, в каждом около 10 элементов из 50.  RecyclerView, да, либо вместо notifyDataSetChanged вручную проходится проходится по всем child каждого ListView и обновлять текст.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    timer.cancel();
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    try {
       timer = new Timer();
       timerTask = new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              //Обновляем вью
          }
       };
       timer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 2000);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
       android.util.Log.i("Damn", "resume error");
    }
}
```